# Неправильно работают макросы Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, макросы

Значит, пишу такой код (вручную):

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

А после использования макроса появляется такое:

```html
<head>
</head>
<body>
</b<link rel="stylesheet" href=""><html>
</html>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Криво работают макросы Notepad++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/450391/%d0%9a%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-notepad)

Comment: А сам-то макрос какой? Он может как раз и должен делать?